# Display loaded elements with different height (pagination) in grid layout

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout

I have several items (elements) with **different height** but with the same width which I am arranging them with Bootstrap 3. At first, the first 9 of them are displayed in three columns (col-sm-4) and I want to load 3, 6 or 9 more of those items as shown in the picture.

[image: Items Layout]

My question is if there is a way in order to display the loaded items in that order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want do it by using css check out this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts)

Otherwise, you have to use a jQuery plugin like [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/) or [Isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/

Comment: Seriously, I do not know how to thank you. Your answer was exactly what I wanted. For the interest of everyone, I have used the implementation which is described on the last link (w3bits.com) that @karthik edited into his answer.

Comment: Welcome!! I'm glad that you found the solution.:-)